# Slow search in Windows 2012 R2 start menu

Tags: windows-server-2012, search, windows

I'm using Windows Server 2012 R2 (full version, not core).

When I start to type the name of a program in the start menu, there is a latency of several seconds before results are suggested.

I suspect that, unlike Windows 8, there's no indexation of the start menu content (nearly immediate with W8).

Is there something I can activate in order to get acceptable search performance in the start menu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had the exact same problem in my Windows Server 2012 R2.

I solved it by installing the feature Windows Search Service. Then it began indexing Start Menu og Users by it self, and now searches are fast like earlier versions of Windows Server. :-)